# Simplifying a Combination with Stirling's Approximation

Tags: limits, binomial-coefficients, stirling-numbers

I'm trying to figure out the value of the following expression using Stirling's approximation:
$$\lim\limits_{h\rightarrow\infty} \binom{kh+h-1}{kh-1}$$

where $k$ is some constant. I want to simplify this enough that I can tell whether this value grows exponentially or super-exponentially.